# QueryFailedError: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause' at Query.onResult

Tags: mysql, database, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm encountering an issue with my Nest.js application after deploying it to Google Cloud Run. The application is designed to retrieve a store based on the client's IP address using the IP's decimal representation for querying the database. While it works perfectly on my local development environment (which uses DBeaver to manually create the database), I'm facing an issue after deploying it to Cloud Run, the database was also created manually for testing via DBeaver. However, I'm encountering the following error:

> QueryFailedError: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause' at Query.onResult (/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:158:37) at Query.execute (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14) at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34) at PacketParser.onPacket (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12) at PacketParser.executeStart (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16) at Socket. (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25) at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28) at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12) at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)

## Context:

I have a service function `getStoreIdByIP` that takes the client's IP address as a string and converts it to a decimal representation using the `ipToDecimal` function.

The `ipToDecimal` function converts IP addresses to decimal format correctly.

The `findStoreByIpNum` function constructs the query using the calculated decimal value to find the corresponding store in the database.

Error Scenario:

Upon triggering the `getStoreIdByIP` function with a client's IP address, I encounter the `QueryFailedError` with the message *"Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'."*

What I've Checked:

I've verified that the `ipToDecimal` function returns the expected decimal representation.

I've examined the query construction in the `findStoreByIpNum` function and ensured that it's using valid decimal values.

I've confirmed that the IP address passed to the `ipToDecimal` function is in the correct format.

I've reviewed my table definition and entity mapping to ensure they match.

**Code Samples:**

Here's an overview of relevant parts of my code:

```
// StoreController
@Get('store-id')
async getStoreByIP(@Req() req: Request): Promise<StoreIdDto | ProblemDto> {
    const ip = req.ip;
    return await this.storeService.getStoreIdByIP(ip);
}

// StoreService
async getStoreIdByIP(ip: string): Promise<StoreIdDto | ProblemDto> {
    const ipDecimal = ipToDecimal(ip);
    const store = await this.findStoreByIpNum(ipDecimal);

    // Rest of the code...
}

// ipToDecimal function
export function ipToDecimal(ip: string): number {
    // Conversion logic...
}

// findStoreByIpNum function
async findStoreByIpNum(ipDecimal: number): Promise<Stores> {
    return this.storeRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('stores')
        .where('stores.ip_min_num <= :ipDecimal', { ipDecimal })
        .andWhere('stores.ip_max_num >= :ipDecimal', { ipDecimal })
        .getOne();
}
```

I'm seeking assistance in identifying the root cause of the *"Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'"* error and how to resolve it. I've checked the code and verified that the calculated decimal value is correct. Any insights or suggestions on where the issue might be originating would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of `ipDecimal` you are passing to the querybuilder. It most certainly is not a valid number, thus the final query spells out as

```
where store.ip_min_num <= NaN
```

instead of

```
where store.ip_min_num <= 17
```

And because this `NaN` is not enclosed in quotes, it's interpreted as a column name, thus the error message.

Probably your `ipToDecimal` function receives an input it can't handle correctly. I don't say it's completly wrong, it may work correctly most of the time. But there seems to be some input it can't process correctly.

I'd suggest to add some exception handling in your `getStoreIdByIP` and whenever this exception occurs, write the the respective IP address string and the result from `ipToDecimal` to the log. Or you can just add a simple check like

```
if (isNaN(ipDecimal)) {
  //log ip address
}
```

befor passing `ipDecimal` on to the next function. This way you can identify and fix the issues with your conversion...

Comment: Thank you very much! You are totally right I got very weird data after all these deployment processes. Also I had an issue with Proxy, as I use Apigee. But now everything is fine! You helped me to move in a right way!